# Bijection between a set of subspaces and a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\pi$ is the plane with equation $x +y+z=0$, find a bijection between the set of subpaces $U$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $U\oplus\pi=\mathbb{R^3}$ and the set of vectors $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R^3}$ that satisfy $a+b+c=1$.

Hints?

Comment: What dimension should $U$ have? Can you think of a way to link a space of that dimension and a vector?

Comment: The first thing I thought was that $U$ is the set of all the lines passing through the origin and not lying in the plane $\pi$. All these lines meet $a+b+c=1$ just once and there is a line connecting every point of $a+b+c=1$ to the origin. I don't know if my intuition is correct and if I can build a proof out of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$, show that $U=\operatorname{span}(x)$ satisfies $U\oplus\pi = \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Perfect, should I even show that $U=span(x)$ is bijective?

Comment: Of course you should show that $x\mapsto \operatorname{span}(x)$ is a bijection between the sets you are given. As long as you didn't show that, you have merely guessed a bijection, not found one.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}[0]{\mathbb{R}}$**Hint** Consider such a subspace $U$ such that $\R^{3} = U \oplus \pi$. Clearly $U$ is spanned by any of its nonzero vector, and for any non-zero $v = (c, d, e) \in U$ one will have $c + d + e \ne 0$, as $v \notin \pi$. Therefore the vector
$$
(a, b, c) = \frac{1}{c + d + e} v \in U
$$
satisfies $a + b + c = 1$. Show that there is a unique such vector in each $U$.

Conversely, show that any such $(a, b, c)$ spans a $U$.